# PHP: Is there a null safe operator to prevent "Undefined array key" warning when merging two arrays?

Tags: php

`foo['data']['main']` is a string and `foo['data']['extra']` is an array of strings. I want to merge them together into an `$data` array, but they may not exist.

When I merge it this way...

```
$foo['data']['main'] = 'apple';
$foo['data']['extra'] = ['banana', 'orange'];
$data = array_merge(
  [$foo['data']['main']] ?: [],
  $foo['data']['extra'] ?: []
);
```

...it works fine, but when `main` or `extra` keys do not exist, then I get this message:

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "extra"

Is there a null safe operator that I should use to prevent such warning and make this code nicer ?

Comment: You can use the `@` operator to suppress warnings.

Comment: or use ?? instead ?:

Comment: @Barmar Where do you use `@` operator? I'm still getting the warnings wherever I use it.

Comment: @JanuszO That won't work for the first variant: `[$foo['data']['main']] ?: []`

Comment: have you try to check this out? https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator

Comment: @JanuszO I'm still getting the warnings with `??` instead of `?:`

Comment: @GilangPratama Nullsafe operators are referring to property access, not array access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Null coalescing operator" `??`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Then you will get no "array key does not exists" message if array keys are not set

```
$foo['data']['main'] = 'apple';
$foo['data']['extra'] = ['banana', 'orange'];
$data = array_merge(
  [$foo['data']['main']] ?? [],
  $foo['data']['extra'] ?? []
);
```

Result:

> Array (
> [0] => apple
> [1] => banana
> [2] => orange )

```
$foo['data']['main'] = 'apple';
$data = array_merge(
  [$foo['data']['main']] ?? [],
  $foo['data']['extra'] ?? []
);
```

Result:

> Array (
> [0] => apple )

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `@` operator to suppress warnings.

```
$data = array_merge(
  [@$foo['data']['main']] ?: [],
  @$foo['data']['extra'] ?: []
);
```

Note that `[$foo['data']['main']] ?: []` won't create an empty array by default, with or without the `@` operator (which just suppresses the warning). If the `main` element doesn't exist, this defaults to `NULL`, so it's equivalent to `[NULL] ?: []`. Since `[NULL]` is not an empty array, the ternary operator returns it, not the `[]` default.

So what you need is an ordinary ternary operator, since the null value is at a different level in the array nesting.

```
$data = array_merge(
    @$foo['data']['main'] ? [$foo['data']['main']] : [],
    @$foo['data']['extra'] ?: []
);
```

Comment: Adding `@` doesn't remove the warnings for me

Comment: It's maybe due to my PHP configuration then